# twitch.tv video full screen opens on different monitor?

Tags: nvidia, video, multiple-monitors, streaming

I have a Nvidia eVGA GeForce GTX 680 and I am running three monitors off of it. Whenever I watch the live streams on twitch.tv and I want to watch in full screen via the little button on the bottom of the video, the full screen opens on a different monitor than the window it was running in inside of Firefox. Videos on youtube.com and the like open on the same monitor and are not a problem, it is only twitch.tv. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Hi Z, can you please read the following article and let me know if it helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/driver-to-use-when-installing-an-nvidia-ati-or-intel-video-card

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, but I do have a workaround. Hit the "pop out video" button on twitch, then hit F11 (or go view>fullscreen) to make firefox fullscreen on whatever monitor you like.